# How can i put multiple elementID's in declared 1 variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider, false);

function toggleSlider()
{
    if (slider.classList.contains('opened')) {
        slider.classList.remove('opened');
        slider.classList.add('closed');
    } else {
        slider.classList.remove('closed');
        slider.classList.add('opened');
    }
}
```

Please help me answer my problem in declaring multiple ID's in the toggle arera and slider area to have multiple toggles and sliders?

Comment: please share you target html...

Comment: ID of an element must be unique so you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID

Answer (score 0):

`id`s are supposed to be unique within a document, you need to use `class` to group `toggle`s. Add `toggle` class to the elements, then you can do something like this:

```
var toggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');
```

[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) returns only the first found matching element, use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to query the entire document. Then you can iterate through the returned HTMLCollection and add your eventlisteners.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post HTML. So here is one possible solution:

```
var toggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle'),
    slider = document.querySelectorAll('.slider'),
    opened = document.getElementsByClassName('opened');

// Sort sliders by data-slider id
slider = [].slice.call(slider).sort(function (a, b) {
    return +a.dataset.slider - +b.dataset.slider;
});

for (var i = 0; i < toggle.length; i++) {
    toggle[i].addEventListener('click', toggleSlider, false);
}

function toggleSlider() {
    opened.length && opened[0].classList.remove('opened');
    slider[this.dataset.id - 1].classList.toggle('opened');
}
```

for this HTML:

```
<a class="toggle" data-id="1">Toggle 1</a>
<a class="toggle" data-id="2">Toggle 2</a>
<a class="toggle" data-id="3">Toggle 3</a>

<div class="slider" data-slider="3">Slider 3</div>
<div class="slider" data-slider="1">Slider 1</div>
<div class="slider" data-slider="2">Slider 2</div>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JrE6t/